# Python lib beautiful soup using aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp

someone know how to do :

```
import html5lib
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen('http://someWebSite.com').read().decode('utf-8'), 'html5lib')
```

using aiohttp instead of urllib ?

Thanks ^^

Comment: I'm curious about why you want to do this.

Comment: Because urllib is blocking. And I need a non-blocking librairy

Comment: I can't offer direct advice about your question. However, I understand that blocking can also arise with timeouts. You might be interested in this page: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests ('Blocking Or Non-Blocking?' and 'Timeouts')

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import html5lib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

SELECTED_URL = 'http://someWebSite.com'

async def get_site_content():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(SELECTED_URL) as resp:
            text = await resp.read()

    return BeautifulSoup(text.decode('utf-8'), 'html5lib')

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
sites_soup = loop.run_until_complete(get_site_content())
print(sites_soup)
loop.close()
```

Answer (score 9):

Just for people who is looking for more answers:
there is another way to run synchronous code in loop: ***loop.run_in_executor***.

More in docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor

Example code:

```
import asyncio
import time

def blocking_func():
    time.sleep(5)
    return 42

async def main(loop):
    result = await loop.run_in_executor(None, blocking_func)
    return result

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop_result = loop.run_until_complete(main(loop))
print(loop_result) # => 42
```

So, you can *await* your task like you do it with coroutine