# Keep bot alive even a function is looping

Tags: python

Im developing a discord covid tracker bot and the information is scraped from a facebook page. I successfully scrape the info and store it to a list, however when I run the bot the bot will work at first but for every 5 minute the bot will be disconnect and not responding because `def scrape` will be refresh every 5min. So my question is how can I keep the bot to work even the scrape function is looping?

My code:

```
import discord
import random
import time
import asyncio
from facebook_scraper import get_posts
from discord.ext import commands, tasks

listposts = []

token = 'xxxx'

client = discord.Client()

listposts = []
@tasks.loop(minutes=5)
async def scrape():
    wanted = "Pecahan setiap negeri (Kumulatif)"  # wanted post
    for post in get_posts("myhealthkkm", pages=5):
        if post.get("text") is not None and wanted in post.get("text"):
            # print("Found", t)
            listposts.append(post.get("text"))
        else:
            pass
            # print("Not found")
    print(listposts)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  
    if message.content.startswith("-malaysiacase"):
        await message.channel.send(listposts)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("RUN")

scrape.start()

client.run(token)
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

After 5 minutes (the scrape function reload), the bot couldn't respond to user request anymore until the scraping process completed
[image]

[image]

Comment: I am assuming facebook_scraper module is not asynchronous therefor blocking, which will make your bot freeze till it has completed and miss heartbeats which causes disconnect

Comment: @SimonT yea i guess so, i tried to put the scrape code into `on_ready` function. It worked but the respond will be slower after the scraping complete

Comment: What I understand from async is that you should probably await something (maybe a short sleep) inside the loop to give other code a chance to run.

Comment: do not use `time` module inside a discord bot either you have to use `asyncio.sleep`  The issue here is that facebook_scraper is not async therefore you can't await it @MB-F it simply won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

facebook_scraper module is not asynchronous therefore blocking, which will make your bot freeze till it has completed and miss heartbeats which causes disconnect.

Do not use time module inside a discord bot either you have to use asyncio.sleep for the same reason.

Some alternatives you can do are: use BS4 in conjunction with AIOHTTP.
Or look at running your sync function in loop.run_in_executor.

There are some examples here: [Python lib beautiful soup using aiohttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182014/python-lib-beautiful-soup-using-aiohttp)

Comment: You mean if i used my scrape function in `loop.run_in_executor am able to scrape continuously without stopping my bot?

Comment: I suggest you read up on asyncio and asynchronous code since d.py is built on it: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_in_executor. Essentially yes, running in executor allows you to await sync code