# RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'NewsExtraction.get_article_data_elements' was never awaited

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I have always resisted using `asyncio` within my code, but using it might help with some performance issues that I'm having.

Here is my scenario:

- An end user provides a list of news sites to scrape
- Each element is passed to an `Article Class`
- A valid article is passed to an `Extraction Class`
- The `Extraction Class` passes data to a `NewsExtraction Class`

90% this of the time this flow is flawless, but on an occasion one of the 12 functions in the NewsExtraction Class fails to extract data, which exist in the HTML provide.  It seems that my code is "stepping on itself," which cause the data element not to be parsed.  When I rerun the code all the elements are parsed correctly.

The NewsExtraction Class has this function `get_article_data_elements`, which is called from the Extraction Class.

The function `get_article_data_elements` call these items:

```
published_date = self._extract_article_published_date()
modified_date = self._extract_article_modified_date()
title = self._extract_article_title()
description = self._extract_article_description()
keywords = self._extract_article_key_words()
tags = self._extract_article_tags()
authors = self._extract_article_author()
top_image = self._extract_top_image()
language = self._extract_article_language()
categories = self._extract_article_category()
text = self._extract_textual_content()
url = self._extract_article_url()
```

Each of these data elements are used to populate a Python Dictionary, which is eventually passed back to the End User.

I have been trying to add `asyncio` code to the `NewsExtraction Class`, but I kept getting this error message:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'NewsExtraction.get_article_data_elements' was never awaited
```

I have spent the last 3 days trying to figure this issue out. I have looked at dozens of questions on Stack Overflow on this error `RuntimeWarning: coroutine never awaited`. I have also looked at numerous articles on using `asyncio`, but I cannot figure out how to use `asyncio` with my `NewsExtraction Class`, which is called from the `Extraction Class`.

*Can someone provide me some pointers to solve my issue?*

```
class NewsExtraction(object):
    """
    This class is used to extract common data elements from a news article
    on xyz
    """

    def __init__(self, url, soup):
        self._url = url
        self._raw_soup = soup


    truncated...


    async def _extract_article_published_date(self):
      """
      This function is designed to extract the publish date for the article being parsed.

      :return: date article was originally published
      :rtype: string
      """
      json_date_published = JSONExtraction(self._url, self._raw_soup).extract_article_published_date()
      if json_date_published is not None:
         if len(json_date_published) != 0:
            return json_date_published
         else:
             return None
      elif json_date_published is None:
           if self._raw_soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class': regex.compile("--publishDate")}):
              date_published = self._raw_soup.find(name='div', attrs={'class': regex.compile("--publishDate")})
              if len(date_published) != 0:
                 return date_published.text
              else:
                logger.info('The HTML tag to extract the publish date for the following article was not found.')
                logger.info(f'Article URL -- {self._url}')
                return None


    truncated...


    async def get_article_data_elements(self):
      """
      This function is designed to extract all the common data elements from a
      news article on xyz.

      :return: dictionary of data elements related to the article
      :rtype: dict
        """
      article_data_elements = {}
      
      # I have tried this:
      published_date = self._extract_article_published_date().__await__()

      # and this
      published_date = self.task(self._extract_article_published_date())
      await published_date

      truncated...
```

I have also tried to use:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(NewsExtraction.get_article_data_elements())
    # asyncio.run(self.get_article_data_elements())
```

I'm really banging my head on the wall with using `asyncio` in my news extraction code.

If this question is off base, I will be happy to delete it and keep reading about how to use `asyncio` correctly.

Can someone provide me some pointers to solve my issue?

Thanks in advance for any guidance on using `asyncio`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are defining `_extract_article_published_date` and `get_article_data_elements` as coroutines, and this coroutines must be `await`-ed in your code to get the result of their execution in an asynchronous way.

You can do this creating an instance of type `NewsExtraction` and calling this methods with the keyword `await` in front, this `await` pass the execution to other task in the loop until his awaited task completes its execution. Note that there are no threads or process involved in this task execution, the execution is passed only if it is no using cpu-time (`await`-ing I/O operations or sleeping).

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    extractor = NewsExtraction(...)
    # this creates the event loop and runs the coroutine
    asyncio.run(extractor.get_article_data_elements())
```

Inside your `_extract_article_published_date` you must also `await` your coroutines that perform requests over the network, if you are using some library for the scraping make sure that uses `async`/`await` behind the scenes to get a real performance while using `asyncio`.

```py
async def get_article_data_elements(self):
      article_data_elements = {}
      
     # note here that the instance is self
      published_date = await self._extract_article_published_date()

      truncated...
```

You must dive into the [asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) to get a better understanding of these features of Python 3.7+.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I will most likely mark it as correct as soon as I figure out what is causing this new error:  `sys:1: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'NewsExtraction._extract_article_title' was never awaited
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback`

Comment: Every time that you want to invoke a coroutine (an `async def`) you have to use the keyword `await` in front of it, this schedules its execution in the loop and **awaits** until the coroutine returns. Just what I described in the answer. If you want to do an experiment, copy the "Hello, World"  example from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html#module-asyncio), remove the `await` keyword and it will raise the same warning you are getting.

Comment: Note that this is not an exception, is just a warning because the coroutine is not being scheduled in the loop, probably not what you were expecting to do.

Comment: each function starts with `async def` and I call them like this ` title = await self._extract_article_title()`

Comment: Thanks for your help with this.  I now understand where I was making my mistakes.  I found that I needed to call the  asyncio.run function from another Classes in my program.   I did note that adding async didn't improve the performance of my code.  I'm now on the hunt for something that will improve the performance.

Comment: Glad it worked. Sure, you can use threading, but if you are still intersted in use `asyncio` for the scrapping, maybe you can use `aiohttp` + `bs4`, check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44182014/python-lib-beautiful-soup-using-aiohttp).